# How to test method1 only when it depends on method 2

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Given I have a WCF service with an (example) implementation:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
    void Baz();
}

public interface ISomeDependency
{
    void DoStuff();
}

public class Foo : IFoo
{

    ISomeDependency _someDependency;

    public Foo(ISomeDependency someDependency)
    {
        this._someDependency = someDependency;
    }

    public void Bar()
    {
        // Some stuff

        _someDependency.DoStuff();

        if (1 == 1) // some condition that won't always be true
            this.Baz();
    }

    public void Baz()
    {
        // some stuff

        _someDependency.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

How do I go about unit testing `Foo.Bar`s implementation without caring about the results of `Foo.Baz`?  Specifically, I want to know that Foo.Baz(); was (or wasn't) called depending on how I'm mocking the call to `Foo.Bar`, but don't necessarily want `Foo.Baz`s logic to "fire".

I was originally thinking of doing something like this:

```
public class Foo : IFoo
{
    // ... same as previous

    public virtual void Baz()
    {
        // some stuff

        _someDependency.DoStuff();
    }
}
```

and then in my unit testing project having:

```
public class TestFoo : Foo
{
    public bool IsBazFired { get; private set; }

    public TestFoo(ISomeDependency someDependency)
        : base (someDependency)
    {
        IsBazFired = false;
    }

    public override void Baz()
    {
        IsBazFired = true;
    }
}
```

This way I can see that `Foo.Baz` fired in my testing (though I would have to test with `TestFoo` rather than `Foo`.  Is there another way I can go about doing this?  It seems like little enough work right now, but if trying to implement this all over the place, the code could/would become littered with test implementations of classes.

I don't necessarily like marking my function as `virtual` just so i can stub out an implementation for testing... so I'm hoping there another way.

I'm currently just starting out with the mocking framework `Moq`, if that makes a difference on how to go about accomplishing my desired results.

Comment: You could use mocking frameworks, for example, [FakeItEasy](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy), [NSubstitute](https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute).

Comment: Like Sergii said, without mocking frameworks you have to do it manually like you did.

Comment: I am currently using (or attempting to learn) `Moq`, but haven't worked with concretes yet, only interface mocking

Comment: If you don't want (or cannot) to use `virtual`, there is a mocking framework [Microsoft Fakes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175(v=vs.110).aspx) which can help you to test almost everything using shims. `A shim modifies the compiled code of your application at run time so that instead of making a specified method call, it runs the shim code that your test provides.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I went about accomplishing the tests with `Moq`.

First, mark methods that need to be "stubbed" out as virtual (hopefully this is not considered bad practice):

```
public virtual void Baz()
{
    // some stuff

    _someDependency.DoStuff();
}
```

In your test, you can set up a mock object of a class, rather than an interface.  Up until this point, I was only mocking interfaces:

```
[TestClass]
public class FooTests
{

    Mock<Foo> _mockFoo;
    Mock<ISomeDependency> _mockSomeDependency;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void Setup()
    {
        _mockSomeDependency = new Mock<ISomeDependency>();
        _mockFoo = new Mock<Foo>(_mockSomeDependency.Object);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Testing_BazIsNotCalled()
    {
        _mockFoo.CallBase = true;
        _mockFoo.Setup(s => s.Baz());
        _mockFoo.Object.Bar();

        _mockFoo.Verify(v => v.Baz(), Times.Never);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Testing_BazIsCalled()
    {
        _mockFoo.CallBase = true;
        _mockFoo.Setup(s => s.Baz());
        _mockFoo.Object.Bar();

        _mockFoo.Verify(v => v.Baz(), Times.Once);
    }
}
```

using `CallBase = true` on my mock signifies that anything not explicitly mocked will use the classes implementation.

In my `_mockFoo.Setup(s => s.Baz());` I am overriding the "base" functionality of `Baz()` and providing a new implementation (in this case a stub).  Then I am actually invoking the base `Bar()`, and testing with `_mockFoo.Verify(...);` whether or not the `Baz()` call proceeded.  This verify check is of course based on `if (1==1)` which in this case would always be true, but I just wanted to get some "fake logic" in there so I would have a block to check against.

Note that if you forget to mark your method attempting to be stubbed as virtual, your code will compile fine, but you'll encounter an exception during run time similar to:

> ```
> Result StackTrace:    
> ...
> at Moq.Mock.ThrowIfCantOverride(Expression setup, MethodInfo method)
>    at Moq.Mock.<>c__DisplayClass1c`2.<Setup>b__1b()
>    at Moq.PexProtector.Invoke[T](Func`1 function)
>    at Moq.Mock.Setup[T,TResult](Mock`1 mock, Expression`1 expression, Condition condition)
>
> at Moq.Mock`1.Setup[TResult](Expression`1 expression)
>     at FooTests.Testing_BazIsNotCalled() in UnitTests.cs:line 23
> Result Message: Initialization method Testing_BazIsNotCalled threw     exception. System.NotSupportedException: System.NotSupportedException: Invalid     setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: s => s.Baz()).
> ```

I don't know if I'm using the correct terms for the above (stubs/mocks), but it's working nonetheless.